# Why does Area 51 grant reputation upon verifying your email?

Tags: discussion, reputation, area-51

You get 50 reputation on Area 51 when you verify your email address.

Why is this only for Area 51, and not for other sites? I assume it is to let you gain the basic upvote/comment privileges, but I'm not sure since I haven't seen this on any other site.

Has anything like this been implemented on other Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is answered Area 51's [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

> You'll earn your first 50 reputation by confirming your email address. This allows you to create proposals and example questions.

Since the purpose of the site is to create other new sites and to do that they need to be proposed, Area 51 wouldn't get very far if its users couldn't do that effectively.

Area 51 operates very differently to all other sites because its purpose is unique.

Answer (score 10):

Per the [FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> ### [What is reputation?](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)
>
> Reputation is a (very) rough measurement of how much the overall Area 51 community trusts you. Reputation is never given; it is earned by convincing other users that you know what you're talking about.
>
> You'll earn your first 50 reputation by confirming your email address. **This allows you to create proposals and example questions.**

(emphasis: mine)

It also has this at the end of the FAQ:

> ### [I still have more questions!](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#meta)
>
> If they're about Area 51, please ask in the [Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/). If they're about Stack Exchange in general, though, they're welcome at [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), the Stack Exchange site about Stack Exchange. Either way, somebody may have already asked your question.